# BDD with RestAssured passing oauth2 code before each features

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, rest-assured, cucumber-java

I have my framework currently setup with BDD and rest assured. For each feature files, I have one Scenario . recently we added oauth2 support and im wondering on best approach to take on implementing that Auth2 code support. Oauth2 token last for half an hour so I would want the getAuthToken part to run first and use that token to authenticate for all the features.

Essentially I wane retrieve the bearer token and reuse that for all the api tests

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like VCR (https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs) for this. Basically you get a valid token once, and you record the positive response you get from Oauth using the token. Then you use that recording in all you susbsequent steps and features.

This avoids having to go to Oauth each time you run your features. And should allow you to run your features locally with no network connection at all, and for them all to work. This capability is a fundamental requirement of any usable set of tests.

Hopefully you can find a java equivalent of VCR for your project.

Comment: ill keep an eye out and see if i find something similar to this. Currently stuck as It keeps trying to generate a token for every single feature(test) rather than just taking the response of that one time generate token and using it to authenticate